# Список программ которые запрашивают права администратора или ее функции?

Tags: windows-10, администрирование, windows-7, домен, sccm

Есть пк с доменовской учеткой или локальной. На данный момент группа пк которые в домене имеют политику локальных админов, где мне не нужна к примеру сменить IP адресс вводить пароль от LAPS.

Что-бы понять какие программы требуют права администатора или ее функции, где можно посмотреть?
Нашел журнал событий безопасность, вижу что было затребовано повышение прав,код события 4672(категория задачи = Специальный вход),но какая программа или ее функция и т.д.
Какие еще способы проверить, бо если проверять все программы и ее функцию,можно сойти сума.